# target to a div without reloading the page in javascript

Tags: javascript

i wrote a web page that included some stuff. There, i need to create a  input text box after clicking on a button, but it will be at the bottom due to existing stuff and i can't see the input box as it is in the out of visible area.there i'v to scroll down to find that.I tried with focus method , it focuses to the input box, it is unable to take the input box to visible area.in the top , i'v some javascript stuff .so i need to do this without refreshing.Here is the code snippet i'v tried.

```
<script>

function create(){
var inputBox=document.createElement('input');
inputBox.setAttribute('id','myInput');
var body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; 
body.appendChild(inputBox);
document.getElementById('myInput').focus();
}
</script>

<body>

<button onclick="create()">Click me</button>


</body>
```

Can anyone help me !

Comment: So you want to move the inputbox to the top somewhere? Why not place it there in the first place?

Comment: this is the case.I have created a table at the bigining.here i need to append a table row.as it is in the out of visible area, i need to take that row middle or top of the page.(table cells contain input boxes.That's why i asked about input boxes).

Comment: @manoj please make sure you dont leave out relevant details when paraphrasing a problem . If you are inserting a new tr into a table , you can insert it at any index . Refer http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are inserting the text input as the last element in body. If you want it to appear at a specific place, create a placeholder for it. For instance:

```
<script>

function create(){
var inputBox=document.createElement('input');
inputBox.setAttribute('id','myInput');

var wrapper=document.getElementById('wrapper'); 
wrapper.appendChild(inputBox);

inputBox.focus();
}
</script>

<body>

<button onclick="create()">Click me</button>
<div id="wrapper"></div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a anker:

```
<a name="button"></a>
<button onclick="create()">Click me</button>
```

Then you can jump to it

```
location.href = 'http://yourpage#button'
```

The page will not reload if you jump to an anker on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always have the input in the HTML markup , and make it visible when clicking the button .

Also replacing the

```
body.appendChild
```

with

```
body.insertBefore(inputBox,body.firstChild);
```

should do what you want .